# Firebase cloud massaging post request keep getting denied

Tags: c#, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to implement a function to send a notification message from my C# program using Firebase's API to a mobile client's phone. Since the legacy API is getting removed later this year, I might as will used to V1 version.

I created the following code in my C# program (I modify the variable for privacy reason). But every time I try to post the http request, it gets denied. I'm not sure why.

```
public void sendprocess()
{
    try {
        Console.WriteLine("\n\n sending FCM massage . . . ");
        // Update the file path to the service account key file
        string fileName = "C:/Users/rjsoo/Desktop/API testing/server testing/servicetest1/servicetest1/test3-12345-firebase-adminsdk-p2134fp-224234120a.json";

    string scopes = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.messaging";
    var bearertoken = ""; // Bearer Token in this variable
    using (var stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        bearertoken = GoogleCredential
            .FromStream(stream) // Loads key file
            .CreateScoped(scopes) // Gathers scopes requested
            .UnderlyingCredential // Gets the credentials
            .GetAccessTokenForRequestAsync().Result; // Gets the Access Token
    }

        ///--------Calling FCM-----------------------------
        Console.WriteLine("\n\n -Calling FCM");
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/test3-12345/messages:send"); // FCM HttpV1 API

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", bearertoken); // Authorization Token in this variable

            //---------------Assigning Of data To Model --------------
            Console.WriteLine("\n\n -Assigning Of data To Model");
            var rootObj = new Root
        {
            message = new Message
            {
                token = "cmc7GfS4SG-O......-q5No4ACAgZErzjHsXMZNObE82S", //FCM Token id
                notification = new Notification
                {
                    title = "Notify Title",
                    body = "Notify Body"
                }
            }
        };

            //-------------Convert Model To JSON ----------------------
            Console.WriteLine("\n\n -Convert Model To JSON");
            var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(rootObj);

            //------------------------Calling Of FCM Notify API-------------------
            Console.WriteLine("\n\n --Calling Of FCM Notify API");
            var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        var response = client.PostAsync("", content).Result; // Calling The FCM httpv1 API

            //---------- Deserialize Json Response from API ----------------------------------
            Console.WriteLine("\n\n -- Deserialize Json Response from API -");
            var jsonResponse = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        var responseObj = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Root>(jsonResponse);

            Console.WriteLine("FCM Send Response:");
            Console.WriteLine(jsonResponse);
        }
}
    catch (Exception ex)
     {
        Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

here is the console log

```
 sending FCM massage . . .


 -Calling FCM


 -Assigning Of data To Model


 -Convert Model To JSON


 --Calling Of FCM Notify API


 -- Deserialize Json Response from API -
FCM Send Response:
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Permission 'cloudmessaging.messages.create' denied on resource '//cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/projects/test3-12345' (or it may not exist).",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
        "reason": "IAM_PERMISSION_DENIED",
        "domain": "cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com",
        "metadata": {
          "resource": "projects/test3-12345",
          "permission": "cloudmessaging.messages.create"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I don't think it's any permission issue as I already downloaded the key json file and generate the oath2 for the massage base on that.
I am the only person in the project role so it can't be the role issue (it default to the role owner).
I made sure the FCM API is enable in the Iam-admin portal.
the client token is correct, I tested in the web site. and it is able to received the massage send from there.
yes the project does exists.
I not sure what am I missing